# Transformations of the cubic forms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Is there a way to understand whether there exist linear transformation that brings one cubic form of n variables to another form? In particular one of the examples I am interested in are two cubic forms in 4 variables:

$F_1=x_1 x_2 x_3+x_1 x_3 x_4+ x_1 x_2 x_4+ x_2 x_3 x_4$

$F_2=x_1 x_2 x_3 + x_1 x_3 x_4 + 2x_1 x_2 x_4$

If there is a way to understand whether such transformation exists is there an algorithm allowing to find this transformation?

Comment: surely, there is an algorithm reducing this question to solving a system of polynomial equations with unknowns being the entries of a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: You need to understand the orbits of the action of $\mathrm{GL}(4,K)$ on $S^3(K^4)$. For such questions you need to be more specific about the ground field.

Comment: In your example the answer is no. The surface $F_1=0$ has isolated singularities, while $F_2=0$ is reducible.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: To be fully precise, you would have to also encode the nonsingularity of the transformation matrix as a polynomial inequation. While there are algorithms for this using Grobner bases (you have to check whether a polynomial vanishes all over the zero set of an ideal), the question whether there are better algorithms than that is reasonable. Still, probably math.stackexchange material.

Comment: @abx: Thank you for the suggestion. I was looking for some criteria like this. However could you please elaborate a bit. I would think that $F_2=0$  has node singularities at $(1,0,0,0)$ and its permutations just like $F_1=0$ has. Why is this not a case?

Comment: @Dima Pasechnik: Thank you. That was my first idea. I would only say that there is $4\times 4$ matrix of coefficients in this case. However trying to solve particular example above in Mathematica was not very successful. So I was wondering if the transformation exists at all and if there are more effective algorithms known.

Comment: $F_2$ is divisible by $x_1$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg - of course, non-singularity is important. By the way, perhaps one can do the classical (or geometric?) invariant theory thing here, although the generators of the ring of invariants of 4-ary cubics aren't known IIRC.

Comment: a necessary condition would be, for two smooth surfaces, to check their Schlaefli type: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ea71/7d6897e27a4c9342678981714b40387e3de2.pdf

Comment: the next step, if this didn't work, would be to ask @alex-degtyarev :-)